# Need to take coordinates from table to map

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, sdk, mapkit

I have a project with

1.Table

2.Map

3.Button 
in bar of table.

User adds longtitude and latitude to table and I need pin to be viewed, whatever he printed.

It will be nice if you explain how to do this whith @property.

Sorry my first question.

I have done everything i have Mutabletable, have pin on map but it done by my coordinates from Xcode

```
  MKCoordinateRegion region1 = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0}};
  region1.center.latitude = 50.481705;
  region1.center.longitude = 30.532894;
  region1.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
  region1.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
  [map setRegion:region1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: @Prince That was my first question too after reading the question ;)

Comment: comented)sry my first question

Comment: @Prince edited)some need more?

Comment: i need to send it by @property.

Comment: @Vincent Song can you show ppls example?

Answer (score 0):

You can search doc about MKMapView:

```
(void)addAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
(void)addAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations;

@protocol MKMapViewDelegate
(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you initialize your mapViewController, you can access it's properties with dot notation. You need to have a CLLocation property in your mapViewController and then you can access it in your first view controller like:

```
myMapViewController = [[MyMapViewController alloc] init];
myMapViewController.myCoordinate.latitude = ...
myMapViewController.myCoordinate.longitude = ...
```

Then your property it your mapViewController will have the values you gave it before.